# The only winning move is

Tags: visual, knowledge, steganography

I'm David, a 16-year old boy who likes video games. With my super-cute girlfriend Jennifer, I hacked into NORAD and started playing "Global Thermonuclear War" with the supercomputer WOPR. Then, Joshua, the AI in the computer, started playing the game for real.
When I tried to end the game, the array of huge Cathode Ray TVs at NORAD showed these images:

[image]

but I don't know what to do now.

> Together we can fix this, right? What do we do?

---

<sub>Codes at the bottom of the screen:</sub>
`0110    1111    0000    1100    0000    0110    0111    0011    1110`
`0110    1111    1100    1000    0011    0110    0110    0001    0110`
`1111    0110    0110    1000    0110    1111    0011    0001    1100`
`1111    0110    0010    1101    0100    1111    0000    1011    0000`

Comment: we can only see the screen? no enter anything to anywhere?

Comment: The thing is that i thought that the numbers will correspond to the squares but then there is `1111` which is 15 so i dropped the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this solution a chance... ;)

> If you take each 4-by-4 block of zeroes and ones and arrange them in a 3-by-3 grid in this order:
>
> ```
>  5 2 3 
>  4 1 8 
>  7 6 9
> ```
>
> Then it gives you the following image:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Peace! The only winning solution.

Comment: Nicely put. [Here's an animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBmVP.gif).

Comment: I dont really understand, from where you can get those positioning number?

Comment: How did you manage to find this??

Comment: @malioboro: I assumed that the mirrored blocks probably went on the side columns and the symmetric blocks down the center. I noticed there appeared to be a circular pattern on the edges, and it just took a little trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if this gets us anywhere, but if we

> convert the binary to hexadecimal,

We get the following sequence:

> ```
>     6    F    0    C    0    6    7    3    E 
>     6    F    C    8    3    6    6    1    6 
>     F    6    6    8    6    F    3    1    C 
>     F    6    2    D    4    F    0    B    0
> ```

I haven't been able to decode this as of yet.

Comment: You have a [tag:visual] tag, but not a [tag:math] or [tag:computer-science] tag, so this probably isn't the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Answer based off the *visual* tag on this question:

> **World Peace or Peace**
>  Theres a visual pattern occurring across the blocks of numbers:
>  • Blocks 1 and 2 are flipped while blocks 1 and 6 are matches
>  • Blocks 3 and 5 are mirrored
>  • Blocks 7 and 9 are mirrored
>
>  Based on a few other answers to this question, if you color in the pattern based on the numbers and arrange the colored blocks on the Tic-Tac-Toe board then you get an image of a Peace symbol.

Secondary answer based off of the *trivia* tag on this question:

> In the movie *War Games* the only winning move is **not to play**. Joshua learns that there can be no winners in nuclear war so it is proven futile to play a game that can't possibly have any winners. Joshua proposes to play a game of chess instead.

Comment: That is the end of the title phrase (and the plot of the movie), but not the answer to this puzzle. The codes at the bottom of the image will be used and explained in a complete answer (one that will be accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image above,

> I arranged the 9 blocks of binary according to a 3x3 square. I got several versions of them though. But I think it's this one:
>
>   `0000 1111 0000`
>   `0011 1111 1100`
>   `0110 0110 0110`
>   `0100 0110 0010`
>
>   `0011 0110 1100`
>   `0001 0110 1000`
>   `0001 1111 1000`
>   `1011 1111 1101`
>
>   `0111 0110 1110`
>   `0110 0110 0110`
>   `0011 1111 1100`
>   `0000 1111 0000`

I'll be back when I figure out what it means

> or which arrangement holds meaning.

Comment: I don't think you've transcribed the blocks correctly. I've edited your post to separate them slightly (feel free to undo this! choose (rollback in [edit history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/71525/revisions) to do so). The middle top block and middle bottom block don't exist in the original post.

Comment: Ah right. My bad. Fixed that, thanks. One more thing @Chowzen, can you help me hide the answer in a spoiler tag? I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: The spoiler tags can be really fussy! Like... ***really fussy!***

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I did colored them in a grid where 1s are yellows and 0s are black. Don't know if it is anything. https://imgur.com/c5YEJXy

Answer (score 0):

Using @Foolish 's grid, and @Takeshi 's art, I made this answer:

> Pixel art of all the numbers together with no gaps. You should be able to open it in a new page and zoom in.
>  [image: pixel art of binary]